# Groups/People Lists not allowing lookup

Tags: infopath, person

I have been trying to turn request forms into InfoPath Forms. However, I am having some issues with the person/group pickers. If I use the default Person picker (the ones that show up when you make a new list on SharePoint) everything works just fine. I can add people, and the website will find them, and often autofill all their information for me.

But when I try to add one of those fields to the InfoPath files they don't allow for any form of lookup, and I'm not sure the information that these fields will hold will work with Microsoft Flow.

How can I get my InfoPath person fields to act like a person field in a list?

To further explain why I can't just use the default lists, here is a screenshot of one of the lists that I am trying to format correctly:
[image]

EDIT:
For further clarity, here is the SharePoint Person field:
[image]
And here is the InfoPath field:
[image]

Note the two new buttons that I don't really want, and the fact that my name did not pop up at all...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by person fields in a list allowing a lookup while infopath people pickers don't?

Comment: @Mike2500 If I use the fields that sharepoint makes, I can type the first three letters of a name, and then the field will usually give me the option to have it autofill the rest of the name. If I use the InfoPath fields, I can type my full name and it still doesn't feel like it recognized me. They even look different! I added an edit to show you the difference.

Comment: The two buttons are what provide that functionality. Type in a few characaters and click the checkbox button. If there is one match, then it confirms the name. If several match, then it will underline your entry in red. At this point, click on the red underlined entry, and you will get a pick list of users that matched. Or, click the little book icon to get to a search page.

Comment: @Mike2500 Thanks! Do you know a way to make them act like the other field anyway, as I am not sure if this will make filling out some of the forms too difficult for our less tech savvy employees...

If not, I'll just have to add this info to the help page, not gonna kill myself over such a small detail...

Comment: No, that's just the InfoPath behavior. (one of the reasons MS is working on replacing IP is that it was created about 15 years ago, before the days of features like autocomplete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the list as a normal SharePoint list, and then customized it with InfoPath. The resulting person field will work fine with Flow. If you have a field named "traveler", in Flow you will have access to several fields, including traveler email, traveler display name, traveler manager, etc.

Comment: That is not the case, as I have tried just editing existing lists this way. It will convert them to the "bad" fields when I open it with InfoPath

Comment: Hmm. I just added a person field to a native sp list, clicked the "customize in infopath" button in the ribbon and published the form. I was then able to create a flow that utilized the person field and was able to get the person's name and email.